# How to get id from User model in django

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models, django-forms

I have the following code:

```
user=User.objects.get(username=uid)
```

I pass the value for uid via url "/profile/showprofile/{{post.author}}". My post.author contains value as "dean88".

When run the form and click on the link with the above mentioned url. i get an error saying **invalid literal for int with base 10 "dean88"**.

But when i go to python shell and give: user=User.objects.get(username='dean88') i still get the same error. The error goes only when i enter the id of the user as integer. Like, user=User.objects.get(username=2).

What can be the problem and how to avoid it?

Comment: Is the `User` you refer to the django default `User` model?

Comment: yes. It refers to django's User model

Comment: `dean88` does not look like an id, which is an integer. Try changing that to `{{post.author.id}}`

Comment: after further reading your OP twice, I think you must have created the user assigning the wrong values to the `.username` attribute (i.e. instead of `dean88` the user was created with `2` as a username. You can check via the admin interface, or even better through `pgadmin` on the DB data directly)

Answer (score 4):

You are currently getting a "dean88" value for your url kwarg because you are passing it the string representation of post.author, that is the username.
Use "/profile/showprofile/{{post.author.pk}}" instead, to pass the actual user id.

Comment: that was my assumption as well (see my comment above). However, it does not explain why `user=User.objects.get(username='dean88')` throws an error, while `user=User.objects.get(username=2)` works.

Comment: @Pynchia.. The code user=User.objects.get(username=2) does not work in my shell. It throws an error saying  "Object_name does not exist. User matching query does not exist"

Comment: you are right! we need to see more code to figure it out.

Comment: I am sorry, I must have misunderstood then, I think your post lacks the word `away`. Good then all solved, as initially assumed by myself and @suselrd, right?

Comment: @suselrd.. By the way "/profile/showprofile/{{post.author.pk}}"  this is not returning any value. Only if use "/profile/showprofile/{{post.author.id}}" it is returning the id back to views.py. Don't know why. Any thoughts on it.

Answer (score 0):

models.py

```
def __str__(self):
       return '{}- {}'.format(self.pk, self.name)
```

this code resquest id in database and show in django admin panel, when you use this code you can  easyli finde posts and comment with id

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score -1):

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> user = User.objects.filter(username='paolocooper12').first()
>>> print(user)
>>> print(user.id)
```

thats how you would do in python manage.py shell